# Accessing coordinates within each curve of SVG

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qtgui, qtsvg

I am using Qt framework to develop a desktop application. I want to load, do some modification and save. So I basically need to access some coordinates within each curve (i.e. control points for Bezier curves, or just even vertices of polylines). I thought of using SVG format, loading it with QtSvg. **Now the question is, after I load SVG (with QGraphicsSvgItem?), how can I look into it, i.e. access separate elements and their coordinates?**

Thanks!

Comment: Now I am able to load and display the image using QFile and QGraphicScene. I have looked into Qt SVG C++ Classes and found these. QGraphicsSvgItem :that can be used to render the contents of SVG files
QSvgGenerator: Paint device that is used to create SVG drawings
QSvgRenderer: Used to draw the contents of SVG files onto paint devices
QSvgWidget: Widget that is used to display the contents of Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) files. But could not find a class that allows me to do manipulation to an existing SVG image. So may I know is it possible to do manipulation directly in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But could not find a class that allows me to do manipulation to an existing SVG image. So may I know is it possible to do manipulation directly in Qt?

It is not possible to edit with QtSvg. It is only for reading.

That is also the reason why the Calligra project had their own way of doing this. There is some SVG support available with webkit, and that may be able to manipulate, but that may also be an overkill for your project.